# How can I percent encode only special characters in python?

Tags: python, urlencode

I'd like to percent encode all occurrences of [RFC 3986 Reserved Characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2) (except `/`) in a string, without encoding the full set of non-ASCII unicode characters.

For example:

`quote('/help?/El Niño #3')` would yield `/help%3F/El Niño %233`

**Possible solutions**

`urllib.parse.quote` is close, especially when using the `safe` parameter.
However, I'd have to pass the full set of non-ASCII unicode characters in the `safe` parameter to make it work.  Turns out there's **lots** of those - not sure I can type them all in myself.

Alternatively, I could chain together 17 `.replace()` statements.
This seems more do-able, but still feels like there must be a simpler way to achieve it...

Comment: Why not just replace `/` with a unique valid combination and then use `urllib.parse.quote`? Or save all positions of `/` and inline-insert `/` back into position after using `urllib.parse.quote`?

Comment: @Torxed The `/` characters aren't the problem here as they can be ignored using `urllib.parse.quote`'s `safe` parameter. (In fact, it defaults to doing so). The problem is all the non-ASCII unicode characters which also get encoded.

Comment: Ah, didn't know urllib replaced those even tho I should probably have remembered that it would (but there's no example output in the question so my lazy memory assumed stuff).